# How can we solve this geometry problem using Lagrange Multipliers? It is must to use the given formula of area.

Tags: nonlinear-optimization, lagrange-multiplier, mathematical-modeling

[image: The problem is here!]

---

The problem is belongs to Mathematical Modeling with Excel book.

Comment: Please transcribe using MathJax so that this question can be understood even if Imgur is down. Also, please provide a full reference.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange! Could you show us your ideas and thoughts on this question?

Answer (score 0):

With $A = \frac 12 a b\sin\theta$, the lagrangian can be build as

$$
L(a,b,c,\theta,\lambda_1,\lambda_2) = A + \lambda_1(a+b+c-l_0)+\lambda_2(c^2-a^2-b^2+2a b\cos\theta)
$$

after that, the stationary points determination is made by solving

$$
\nabla L = 0 = \left\{
\begin{array}{l}
 \lambda_2 (2 b \cos (\theta )-2 a)+\frac{1}{2} b \sin (\theta )+\lambda_1 \\
 \lambda_2 (2 a \cos (\theta )-2 b)+\frac{1}{2} a \sin (\theta )+\lambda_1\\
 2 c \lambda_1+\lambda_2\\
 \frac{1}{2} a b \cos (\theta )-2 a b \lambda_2 \sin (\theta ) \\
 a+b+c-l_0 \\
 2 a b \cos (\theta )-a^2-b^2+c^2 \\
\end{array}
\right.
$$

giving

$$
\left(
\begin{array}{ccccccc}
A & a & b & c & \theta& \lambda_1 & \lambda_2\\
 0 & 0 & \frac{l_0}{2} & \frac{l_0}{2} & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & \frac{l_0}{2} & \frac{l_0}{2} & \pi  & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & \frac{l_0}{2} & 0 & \frac{l_0}{2} & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & \frac{l_0}{2} & 0 & \frac{l_0}{2} & \pi  & 0 & 0 \\
 -\frac{l_0^2}{12 \sqrt{3}} & \frac{l_0}{3} & \frac{l_0}{3} & \frac{l_0}{3} & -\frac{\pi }{3} & \frac{l_0}{6 \sqrt{3}} & -\frac{1}{4 \sqrt{3}} \\
 \frac{l_0^2}{12 \sqrt{3}} & \frac{l_0}{3} & \frac{l_0}{3} & \frac{l_0}{3} & \frac{\pi }{3} & -\frac{l_0}{6 \sqrt{3}} & \frac{1}{4 \sqrt{3}} \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$